# How are valid transactions distributed to block authoring nodes?

Tags: substrate-node-template, consensus, aura

I am new to Substrate and currently reading through all the great documentation that is available.
I understand the concept of block authoring and finalization, but the following is a bit unclear
to me:

Each node of my network can have their own RPC endpoint that can be used to send transactions
to that node, which then will be validated and placed into the transaction pool of that node until
it is put into a block.

Now, when my network uses a round robin authoring algorithm like AURA, I wonder how the node that
is currently selected to auther the next block is aware of transactions withing transaction pools
of other nodes? Is every node gossiping their enitre transaction pool to any other node, so every node
of the network is aware of each valid transaction that was send to any RPC endpoint? Or does a valid
transaction stay in the transaction pool of a node until it is that node's turn to auther a new block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [default](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/primitives/runtime/src/transaction_validity.rs#L293), every valid transaction is [propagated](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/master/substrate/client/transaction-pool#propagate) across the network of peers. There are some cases it is not.

> This parameter instructs the pool propagate/gossip a transaction to node peers. By default this should be true, however in some cases it might be undesirable to propagate transactions further. Examples might include heavy transactions produced by block authors in offchain workers (DoS) or risking being front runned by someone else after finding some non trivial solution or equivocation, etc.

And if you search for `propagate: false` in the repo, you will find couple of cases, namely for [`grandpa`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/grandpa/src/equivocation.rs#L274), `babe` and `beefy` for cases when an equivocation is submitted.